# Can two item renderers be used for a grid column in Adobe flex?

Tags: actionscript, flex4, mxml

I have a data grid with multiple columns among which one is for stock date. Based on the data i am getting from the backend,when a flag is disabled,i want the date to be displayed as a label,otherwise i want the start date to be editable date field. How can this be done?  I have tried this below code but its takes the last rendered item as item renderer. Cause as i loop in,the condition for different records change and rendering it this way doesnt seem to work. Please help.

```
private function resultHandler_tbd(event:ResultEvent):void{
var myAC: ArrayCollection= event.result as ArrayCollection; //data from backend
  myDataGridId.dataprovider= myAC;
for(var i:int=0;i<myAC.length;i++){
   mylist=myAc[i];
   if(mylist.tbdType=="Plan" && flag==true){
   plnStartDate.itemrenderer= new ClassFactory(CustomCalenderRenderer);
   }else
   plnStartDate.itemrenderer = new ClassFactory(CustomLabelRenderer);
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the "flag" property set in data for item renderer

Create a custom itemrenderer which will have both component, CustomCalenderRenderer and CustomLabelRenderer and binded with data.flag for includedInLayout or not

Thanks

Comment: meaning a renderer inside a renderer? Or you mean a renderer class which has both mx components Label and DateField?

Comment: I meant a renderer which will have both component and includedInLayout based on the data.flag. All you have to do is to place the flag prop in the collection and then bind includedInLayout of both component to data.flag.